# dotNet Task does not contain definition for 'Status'

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

The following code does not resolve.

```
        dbRef.GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            switch (task.Status)
            {
```

I get the error: *'Task' does not contain a definition for 'Status'.*

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the reference documentation for the [`Task` class](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/system/threading/tasks/task#class_system_1_1_threading_1_1_tasks_1_1_task) that error message seems to be correct: a task doesn't have a `Status` property. If you want to check whether the task completed successfully or failed, use its `IsCompleted`, `IsFaulted` and/or `IsCancelled` properties.